# exam class and align* environment

Tags: align, exam

I wonder if there is a conflict between the `align` environment and the exam class. I have the following and it gives an error for `\begin{align*}`

```
\documentclass[answers,11pt]{exam}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\title{xxx}
\author{yyy}
\date{ }   

\begin{document}
\maketitle

Please submit the answers by placing hard copy solutions in the assignment boxes.


\qformat{\textbf{Question~\thequestion.} \hfill} 

\begin{questions}
\question Given the following histories:

\begin{align*}
H_{1} = & \{W_{2}(x), W_{1}(x), R_{3}(x), R_{1}(x), W_{2}(y), R_{3}(y), R_{3}(z), R_{2}(x)\} \\
H_{2} = & \{R_{3}(z), R_{3}(y), W_{2}(y), R_{2}(z), W_{1}(x), R_{3}(x), W_{2}(x), R_{1}(x)\} \\
H_{3} = & \{R_{3}(z), W_{2}(x), W_{2}(y), R_{1}(x), R_{3}(x), R_{2}(z), R_{3}(y), W_{1}(x)\} \\
H_{4} = & \{R_{2}(z), W_{2}(x), W_{2}(y), W_{1}(x), R_{1}(x), R_{3}(x), R_{3}(z), R_{3}(y)\}
\end{align*}

\begin{parts}
\part Which of the above histories are conflict equivalent and why?
\part Which of the above histories are serializable and why?
\end{parts}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You're aware you're not loading `amsmath` (which you need), are you?

Comment: Real red face -- no, I had totally missed that straightforward issue. Thanks much.

Comment: don't worry, it happens to all of us :) except egreg :)

Comment: @cgnieder: Started typing my answer before your comment (+1 for it) but was too slow. Well, should this be closed as too localized now?

Comment: @Stephen probably, @ ozso: never mind :)

Answer (score 2):

The `align` (and `align*`) environment is defined by the [amsmath](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) package. Thus you need to add `\usepackage{amsmath}` to your preamble. I would place it immediately before `\usepackage{amssymb}`, thus that the AMS packages are loaded one after the other.